# Create list of combination with value 1

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to list the combinations with value 1. My data is similar to:

```
d = {'Australia' : pd.Series([0,1,1], index=['Australia', 'Belgium', 'France']),
     'Belgium' : pd.Series([1,0,1], index=['Australia','Belgium', 'France']),
    'France' : pd.Series([1,1,0], index=['Australia','Belgium', 'France'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

How could I create a list which would be similar to:

```
> [(Australia, Belgium), (Australia, Belgium), (Belgium, Australia),
> (Belgium, France), (France, Australia), (France, Belgium)]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and export `MultiIndex` to `list of tuples`:

```
s = df.stack()

L = s[s == 1].index.tolist()
print (L)

[('Australia', 'Belgium'), ('Australia', 'France'), 
  ('Belgium', 'Australia'), ('Belgium', 'France'), 
  ('France', 'Australia'), ('France', 'Belgium')]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
Australia  Australia    0
           Belgium      1
           France       1
Belgium    Australia    1
           Belgium      0
           France       1
France     Australia    1
           Belgium      1
           France       0
dtype: int64
```